# Is it possible to remove the Villager GUI and replace it with other right click abilities?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The title is a mouthful, I know, but basically my question is exactly what Wynncraft managed to do. When right-clicking a villager, you would normally open their trading GUI. However, is there a way in Vanilla Minecraft to replace the opening of the GUI with let's say... activating a tellraw command? If you need a visual, I suggest going to the server "play.wynncraft.com" and interacting with the NPCs there.

Comment: I dunno... maybe place a custom coded sign behind it? Many servers, Wynncraft most likely included, use customised Villager GUIs applied through plugins. On MCOrigins (mc.mcorigins.com) almost all villagers have a "pre-menu", selecting what kind of trades that come up. This is particularly evident in Eggwars. This server uses very many plugins, and I doubt your problem can be solved without turning to the dark side (mods)

Comment: Yeah, AFAIK this is not possible without server plugins or mods.

Comment: While managing this would be easier with mods, it is definitely very possible in vanilla; villagers don't have a GUI to open if there are no trades, and there are various methods of detecting a right-click action using commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a villager is summoned without trades, right-clicking it will not open an interface. While detecting who right-clicked it is not particularly accurate, it is possible to do so in vanilla.

### Prerequisites

Villager to summon, with a label for targeting that specific villager.

```
1.11+   /summon minecraft:villager ~ ~1 ~ {Offers:{},Tags:["talk"],NoAI:1b}
1.8     /summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {Offers:{},CustomName:"talk",NoAI:1b}
```

The `stat.talkedToVillager` objective-type increments each time a player interacts with a villager, regardless of if it opened an interface or not:

```
/scoreboard objectives add clickVillager stat.talkedToVillager
```

### Clock commands

The following must be run in numerical order on a clock.

1. Cause the specific villager to run a `/tellraw` command targeting the closest player within 5 blocks that has a "clickVillager" score of 1+.

   ```
   1.11+   /execute @e[type=minecraft:villager,tag=talk] ~ ~ ~ /tellraw @a[score_clickVillager_min=1,r=5] ["You have right-clicked me."]
   1.8     /execute @e[type=Villager,name=talk] ~ ~ ~ /tellraw @a[score_clickVillager_min=1,r=5] ["You have right-clicked me."]
   ```
2. Reset playerscores to 0 to allow future detection.

   ```
   /scoreboard players set @a[score_clickVillager_min=1] clickVillager 0
   ```

If multiple villagers are clumped together, then it will not be directly possible to distinguish who clicked which villager (which is where mods would shine with accuracy).

Comment: Is this all possible to do in 1.8.9 by chance? If not that's 100% fine, I'm just too lazy to download resource packs, Optifine, and WorldEdit for the more recent updates haha.

Comment: Oh also, where would you add a NoAI for the Villager summon command?

Comment: Final question, when activating the tellraw commands, I would do the tellraw, then the reset, and then I can have another tellraw command runnng from there, which then activates the next reset, and so on?

Comment: @KompriZe It'll work in 1.8, yes. I've added commands specific to 1.8, as well as added `NoAI`. The reset would run a single time and only *after* all `/tellraw` commands run. If you reset their score between each `/tellraw`, the player isn't going to have a score to detect after the first reset.

Comment: Oh um, does the /tellraw work in the JSON format when it is part of /execute?

Comment: Because I may plan on adding things like colors and bold and such.

Comment: @KompriZe for colors etc in tellraw, you can use some already existing tools, like this: https://www.minecraftjson.com/ . Btw yes, this should work, however you can only run commands, not anything like custom guis etc. Problem is that it is console calling the command, not the player. Thus no client-side thingie like GUI can be shown, because the server won't recognize it, it will see console as executor. For that, at least one plugin or mod somewhere has to be included.

Comment: @AntoineHejlík I am making a single player world, so... I don't know if that affects your answer.

Comment: @Skylinerw I now have two villagers, however, I've run into a problem.  I've used the following code to activate the first line of text for this character. `/execute @e[type=Villager,name=Brigadier General Joanna Kell] ~ ~ ~ /tellraw @a[score_clickVillager_min=1] [{"text":"[1/x]","color":"gray"}, {"text":"[","color":"dark_green"}, {"text":"Brig. Gen. Kell","color":"green"}, {"text":"]","color":"dark_green"}, {"text":"Ah, Lieutenant Colonel Solter. I heard you would be arriving soon. Take a seat, please.","color":"white"}]` However, the Command Block says,

Comment: `[16:37:48] The entity UUID provided is in an invalid format`

Comment: @KompriZe You cannot have spaces in selectors. You'll need to use some other method of targeting the villager, such as giving it a score.

Comment: @Skylinerw what do you mean by a "score"? Also, how can I do that?

Comment: @KompriZe Scoreboards are a large and complicated topic. I recommend looking up tutorials about them; the wiki has an overview [here](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Scoreboard).

Comment: @Skylinerw so if I spawn a villager with the following tags `/summon Villager ~ ~ ~ {Offers:{},CustomName:"Brigadier General Joanna Kell"",NoAI:1b}` can I possibly add a tag to it? So maybe like `/summon Villager ~ ~ ~ {Offers:{},{Tags:["2"]}CustomName:"Brigadier General Joanna Kell",NoAI:1b}`?

Comment: And in the `/execute` command, I could do

`/execute @e[type=Villager,{Tags:["2"]}] ~ ~ ~ /tellraw @a[score_clickVillager_min=1] [{"text":"[1/x]","color":"gray"}, {"text":"[","color":"dark_green"}, {"text":"Brig. Gen. Kell","color":"green"}, {"text":"]","color":"dark_green"}, {"text":"Ah, Lieutenant Colonel Solter. I heard you would be arriving soon. Take a seat, please.","color":"white"}]`

Theoretically speaking, of course. I honestly am not amazing with commands.

Comment: @KompriZe The `Tags` list doesn't exist in 1.8, which is why I have commands specific to 1.8 that uses `CustomName` instead in the answer. As far as I can remember, you can only use scores in that version. I would highly recommend updating as you're quite a few versions behind.

Comment: @Skylinerw okay so (hopefully) this is the last problem I run into. I'm running `Version 1.9.4` now, and I'm using `tags`. I currently have two villagers, one has the tag `Commander` and the other has the tag `JoannaKell`. The problem is, when I right click either villager, it activates each character's dialogue (ie. the `/execute` commands) Does the tag in `/execute @e[type=minecraft:villager,tag=Commander]` not affect which villager activates which `/execute` command?

Comment: @KompriZe You need to add a radius to the `/tellraw` commands so that it selects only players nearby, otherwise both villagers are going to find you since you'd match the selector they're looking for. As well, you should have at least updated to 1.11, which is the latest version as 1.9 is still very outdated. As shown in my answer, the commands are specifically for 1.11+, though the primary difference would be entity IDs, where pre-1.11 you'd need to use `@e[type=Villager]` rather than `@e[type=minecraft:villager]`.

Answer (score 2):

This thing is maintained by customization of server. Most known and used is Spigot and Forge. Spigot focuses on only server-side changes (aka  popularly called "plugins"), Forge can manage similar, but also extensively uses client modifications as well (aka "mods").

In the villager case you have two possibilities, one is better to use with Spigot, second with Forge. Wynncraft and a lot other servers use Spigot-like way (even though they have their own version of server for sure!), when keeping the villager and just catching your actions. When such an action is detected (your click), it is cancelled and custom action is fired instead. Then, it can "talk" or do other things.

Therefore there is no Vanilla way, because you cannot catch click events or similar. All you can do is to read stats (like how many times you talked to villager), but it is kinda messy to use in real life. You would make better to let them press some pressure plate, iniciating redstone for /tellraw , it will be less painful to setup.

Forge aproach might do the same, but it can do one more thing - simply remove the villager and replace it with custom one (which can, but does not need to look same), with custom actions, custom trades, custom GUIs etc. Then it depends fully on how the villager is supposed to be by new code.

---

There is one big difference between those though - On spigot server, anyone can join with vanilla clients, but if you want to join Forge server, you need to have installed same mods as the server, so you have all added/modified thingies.

---

For your real usage, you should look for Spigot plugins, that come already prepared to do the job and is primarily aimed for begginers. Search https://spigotmc.org for what you need exactly, or write your own plugin/mod if you won't be satisfied by supply.

Comment: Okay, that explains how servers are able to do that. Thank you, that might come in handy later for my friend, as he was considering such actions for his server.

Comment: @KompriZe Writing a plugin should be rather easy, working with events is real basic for Spigot/Bukkit and there is extensive API for doing so. However there is probably already something for that released to everybody, so servers use it. Sadly cannot tell you names, as I don't use those, my aim is for Forge mods :)

Comment: I am not using a server, so I can't use plugins. It's a single player world I am making, and I intend to keep it mod-free. Thank you though :)